# How to apply validation on backend customer custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2

We have tried to apply validation on customer custom attribute at frontend using frontend_class but this way does not apply on the backend.

what other method is used to apply validation at the backend?

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're using to add the attribute to the backend form.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

Use the following way:

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\EavValidationRules">
        <plugin name="custom_attribute_validation" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\EavValidationRules" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\EavValidationRules.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;

class EavValidationRules
{
    public function afterBuild(\Magento\Ui\DataProvider\EavValidationRules $subject, $result, $attribute)
    {
        if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == "custom_attribute_code")
        {
            $validationClasses = explode(' ',$attribute->getFrontendClass());
            $rules = [];
            foreach ($validationClasses as $class)
            {
                $rules[$class] = true;
            }
            return $rules;
        }
    }
}
```